# adding more row in table on button click event in form

Tags: php, jquery

I have a row with id contact list. I want to add two more row below(append to) it on button click event. I have button with id addmorecontacts.

My structure of code is...

```
<?php $contacts=mysql_query("SELECT cntctnum, cntcttype FROM contacts WHERE rfrnc='".$pgid."'") or die(mysql_error());
 while ($resultcontacts=mysql_fetch_assoc($contacts)) {
 $contactnumber = explode("-", $resultcontacts["cntctnum"] );  ?>
     <tr >
        <td class="spacing1">Contact Number:</td>
        <td class="spacing1" >
        <input type="text" id="a" tabindex="5" name="txtphone" value="<?php echo  $contactnumber[0]; ?>" onKeyUp="next()" onChange="change2()" class="a" maxlength="3" size="2"/>
        <b>-</b>
        <input type="text" id="b" name="txtphone1" tabindex="6" value="<?php echo  $contactnumber[1]; ?>" onKeyUp="next(); next2()" onChange="change2()" class="a" maxlength="3" size="2"/>
        <b>-</b>
        <input type="text" id="c" name="txtphone2" tabindex="7" value="<?php echo  $contactnumber[2]; ?>"  onKeyUp="next1()" onChange="change2()"  class="a" maxlength="4" size="3"/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr id="contactlist">
        <td class="spacing1" >Contact Type:</td>
        <td class="spacing1" ><select name="cntcttype" id="cntcttype" tabindex="8" class="select" onChange="change2()">
        <?php  getcontacttype($resultcontacts["cntcttype"]); ?>
        </select></td>
     </tr>
    <?php }  ?>
```

My buton row is...

```
<tr>
            <td class="spacing1" >&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="spacing1" >&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="spacing1" ><input name="addmorecontacts" type="button" value="Add More"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please, explain a little bit better your problem.

Comment: I mean I have to add more row below this rows of contact number and contact type onclick of this button.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to say about the above code is that you will end up with more than one element with the same ID, which is *never* valid. You are generating the `<input>`s in a loop, with static IDs `a,b,c` - you need to either remove these IDs or make then unique to each row. You can use the DB primary key to do this.

In order to add more contacts, you will need a form to allow the user to enter the details, so when your button is clicked you either need to take the user to a new page with the form on it, or have a form appear on your existing page. When the user is happy with the details for the new contact, they need to let you know - so you would have a link/button for them to click which says `Add this contact` or something similar.

Once this button is clicked, you need to send the data to the server, for entry in the database. You could do this by submitting the form in the traditional manner, so the page is reloaded, or you could use AJAX - which method you choose is up to you.

If you submit a form in the traditional manner, you will take the submitted data, pass it through `mysql_real_escape_string()`, and enter it into the database, before redirecting the user back to the original page (the correct HTTP response code for this kind of redirect after a form submission is 303 See Other).

If you use AJAX, the process will be the same as above, but instead of ending with a redirect, you will simply `exit`, and update the display with client-side scripts.

The form submission method is arguably simpler to program, but the AJAX method can be used to give a smoother user experience and (under certain circumstances) reduce server load, since you don't have to completely re-generate the page server side.

Have a go at building some code to do the process as described above, and if you get stuck on anything come back here and we'll be happy to help - but please try and ask questions about specific bits of code that you can't get to work, rather than a generic "how do I do this?" sort of question.

Comment: Sure, Its my mistake that I used same id I should do this using a variable. of php or else. Please help me to improve above code. I need to add whole row using jquery append to above printed row.